# Syntax highlight for Haml/Sass for Coda

Tags: sass, coda

Anyone know where I can get a syntax highlight for Haml/Sass for Coda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the list here: http://sass-lang.com/editors.html

Comment: I know of the list. The sass-mode listed there made by me :)

Comment: link is dead / has moved

Answer (score 4):

Just surfaced :)

https://github.com/secca/Coda-Sass-Plug-in

See also --> https://twitter.com/#!/secca/status/142101466226753536

Answer (score 2):

Here's [HAML syntax highlight for Coda](http://github.com/giannichiappetta/haml.mode), no luck with SASS yet..

On a side note, I recommend to turn on "Show invisible characters" in Coda's preferences to be more aware of possible whitespace/indentation related issues.

Comment: Thanx for the find. If I ever find the time I might use it as a base to create a sass.mode myself. Again, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I have only just installed, and had a quick play around with the project linked to by [fandelost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38400/fandelost), but it certainly seems to be a good place to start.

Comment: There is a sass-mode for Coda now as you can see at http://sass-lang.com/editors.html.