# Sass syntax (not SCSS) highlighting in Coda 2

Tags: sass, coda

In Coda in the menu "Text > Syntax Mode > Sass" is just for .SCSS-syntax. I have been working with .SCSS a while now and would like to try .SASS-syntax.

After searching around I didn't find a solution for this, also not here on SO ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383865/syntax-highlight-for-haml-sass-for-coda) is dated and the answers are not really correct or what I was looking for)

Comment: "We’re looking into adding support for SASS in a future update." -Panic via Mail 14.January 2014... I'm guessing it'll still take a while

Comment: "At this time we don’t have a specific time when SASS highlighting will be supported natively in Coda." 10.11.2015

Comment: Is it still not supported? I have sass 3.1 plugin installed on my Coda 2.5. However the Syntax highlghting does not have the option.

Comment: mhm, I've since switched to Atom. ;) Only thing Coda might be better at is FTP integration, but that's nothing I need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a project on Github which solves this issue. Follow the instructions written in the repository and you are ready to go with .sass files.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/dw2/Sass.mode).